# MongoDB Optional Unique Index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a MongoDB schema for users that looks something like this:

```
{
  userId: "some-string",
  anonymousId: "some-other-string",
  project: {"$oid": "56d06bb6d9f75035956fa7ba"}
}
```

Users must have either a `userId` or an `anonymousId`. As users belong to a project, the model also has a reference called `project`, which links to the project collection.

Any `userId` or `anonymousId` value has to be unique per project, so I created two compound indexes as follows:

```
db.users.createIndex({ "userId": 1, "project": 1 }, { unique: true })
db.users.createIndex({ "anonymousId": 1, "project": 1 }, { unique: true })
```

However as not both `userId` and `anonymousId` have to be provided but *just either one of them*, MongoDB throws a `duplicate key` error for `null` values (for example if there is a second user with a provided anonymousId but no userId).

I therefore tried to add a `sparse: true` flag to the compound indexes, but this obviously only works if both fields are empty. I also tried adding the sparse flag only to the fields and not the compound indexes, but this doesn't work either.

To give an example, let's say I have the following three users in the collection:

```
{ userId: "user1", anonymousId: null, project: {"$oid": "56d06bb6d9f75035956fa7ba"}}

{ userId: "user2", anonymousId: "anonym", project: {"$oid": "56d06bb6d9f75035956fa7ba"}}

{ userId: "user3", anonymousId: "random", project: {"$oid": "56d06bb6d9f75035956fa7ba"}}
```

The following should be possible:

- I want to be able to insert another user `{userId: "user4", anonymousId: null}` for the same project (without getting a duplicate key error)
- However if I try to insert another user with `{userId: "user3"}` or another user with `{anonymousId: "random"}` there should be a duplicate key error

How else can I achieve this?

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.0.9. Are you asking because of partial indexes?

Comment: Indeed. This is intention and will solve lot of your problems. I'll suggest to upgrade database engine if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB 3.2, you can use **unique partial index** instead of sparse index.

Partial index is actually recommended over sparse index

**Example**

```
db.users.createIndex({ "userId": 1, "project": 1 }, 
{ unique: true, partialFilterExpression:{ 
  userId: { $exists: true, $gt : { $type : 10 } } } })

db.users.createIndex({ "anonymousId": 1, "project": 1 }, 
{ unique: true, partialFilterExpression:{ 
  anonymouseId: { $exists: true, $gt : { $type : 10 } } } })
```

In above example, Unique index will only be created when `userId` is present and doesn't contain null value. Same holds true to `anonymousId` too.

Please see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-partial-indexes

Comment: Yes I know, but unfortunately I have to use version 3.0.9. However, how would you do this using a partial index?

Comment: Well in That case you have only one option which I see profesor79 posted above. Create compound index on all three fields.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to give an example how to create a unique partial index in that case?

Comment: sure, can you please update your question and post sample documents covering case you are trying to solve.

Comment: imho partial index will have the same weakness in this case - as there is a business logic needed to handle multiple annon ids and then create an real user id

Comment: Well, not sure what do you mean. But there is no single perfect solution for any given problem.

Comment: @Saleem I added some example data.

Comment: What does the $gt : { $type : 10 } do?

Comment: it check if particular property is not null. It' possibly that a property exists but it contain null value.

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-indexes and read first half of page. you'll see what conditions can be used in expression

Comment: @Saleem Thanks. I the solution works fine - with the correct mongo version. So I'll accept your answer!

Answer (score 1):

index a,c - cannot be sparse as is unique.....

index b,c - cannot be sparse as is unique.....

what about index a,b,c ?

> db.benjiman.insert( {   userId: "some-string",   anonymousId:
>   "some-other-string",   project: {"_oid": "56d06bb6d9f75035956fa7ba"}
>   })
>
> db.benjiman.insert( {   userId: "some-string2",   project: {"_oid":
>   "56d06bb6d9f75035956fa7ba"} })
>
> db.benjiman.insert( {   anonymousId: "some-other-string2",   project:
>   {"_oid": "56d06bb6d9f75035956fa7ba"} })

```
db.benjiman.createIndex({ "userId": 1, "anonymousId": 1, "project": 1 }, { unique: true })
```

Comment: I thought about this too, but the problem with this approach is that it allows to insert the same userId for example if there is a different anonymousId provided.

Comment: ok, have a bigger image now, let's chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104903/mongo-queries-issues