# mongodb combination of fields unique

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I need to ensure combination of some fields to be unique , so i found out we can use indexes to achieve it , like :

```
db.user.ensureIndex({'fname':1,'lname':1},{unique:true})
```

However in my scenario i allow the user to add email or phone or even both . So how do i achieve the uniqueness in this case . I tried like setting 2 indexed like

```
db.user.ensureIndex({'fname':1,'lname':1,'email':1},{unique:true})
```

And

```
db.user.ensureIndex({'fname':1,'lname':1,'mobile':1},{unique:true})
```

this dint work when i try to add a document with email unique , like below

```
> db.user.insert({fname:'tony',lname:'stark',email:'aa@gmail.com'})                                                                                 
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.user.insert({fname:'tony',lname:'stark',email:'xyz@gmail.com'})                                                                             
WriteResult({                                                                                                                             
    "nInserted" : 0,                                                                                                                  
    "writeError" : {                                                                                                                  
            "code" : 11000,                                                                                                           
            "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: temp.user.$fname_1_lname_1_mobile_1 dup key: { : \"tony\", : \"stark\", : null }"                                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                 
 })
```

I guess the error is because of the second index ,since both the inserts have null value for the mobile field . I then tried this

```
db.user.ensureIndex({'fname':1,'lname':1,'email':1,'mobile':1},{unique:true})
```

And that dint help ,is there any way to do this with mongodb or check the uniqueness with code otherwise .

**Update**
I need to ensure uniqueness in this case too :

```
db.user.insert({fname:'tony',lname:'stark',email:'abc@gmail.com'})
<<insert>> 
db.user.insert({fname:'tony',lname:'stark',email:'abc@gmail.com',mobile:554545435}) 
<<dont insert>>
```

**Update 2**
Even Unique partial Index didn't help

```
> db.users.createIndex({ "fname": 1, "lname": 1, "email":1 }, 
... { unique: true, partialFilterExpression:{ 
...   email: { $exists: true, $gt : { $type : 10 } } } })
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.users.createIndex({ "fname": 1, "lname": 1, "mobile":1 }, 
... { unique: true, partialFilterExpression:{ 
...   mobile: { $exists: true, $gt : { $type : 10 } } } })
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 2,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 3,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Here is the query :

```
    >db.users.insert({fname:"tony",lname:"stark",mobile:"123",email:"123@gmail.com"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
>db.users.insert({fname:"tony",lname:"stark",mobile:"123",email:"123@gmail.com"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

**Mongo version - v3.2.0**

I have no experience with mongodb much neither have used indexes in other db's , i guess it's kind of noob question .Thanks in advance

Comment: What about adding separate [sparse](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/) unique indexes on `email` and `mobile`?

Comment: yeah , i found out i can use unique partial index from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770538/mongodb-optional-unique-index

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `$gt : { $type : 10 }` clause in your partial indexes?